# Is there any way to read character type in PHP?

Tags: php

After so much Googling, I still did not find any clue/hint to my question, "Is there any way to read character type in PHP?"

So, if you didn't get a clear idea, let's take this variable for example.

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
```

// the code checks if the $_POST['username'] has any other type of text other than A-Z a-z or 0-9. If it has, it should echo "error!"

Also is there a way to do this:

```
$user = $_POST['name'];
```

// the code checks if the $_POST['name'] has anything other than white spaces, A-Z a-z and dashes, and if it does, it echos "error!"

I hope there is a possibility with PHP as I've seen such things!

Comment: You can use [regexp](http://sg2.php.net/preg_match) for this

Comment: @JörgMäder How so? Can you please provide me some example of such code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should point your eyes to the [ctype_alnum](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) function:

```
if (!ctype_alnum($user))
    echo "error!"
```

Comment: What does alnum mean? and I suppose ctype is character type, I want an explanation of that code.

Comment: 'alnum' means alpha-numeric. From the docs linked above: "Returns TRUE if every character in text is either a letter or a digit, FALSE otherwise."

Comment: I didn't get it, so if(!ctype_alnum($user)) checks if there is only text/numbers and if it doesn't the if statement continues, is it?

Comment: It does exactly this. Consult example in the linked docs on php.net.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, you are really helpful man! It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

May this two example helps. But the whole reg_exp is a big area with many options! But it's worth to learn it! [Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

```
if(preg_match('^[A-Za-z0-9]+$',$user)==1) /* ok */ else /* not ok  */
```

and

```
if(preg_match('^[- A-Za-z0-9]+$',$usernmae)==1) /* ok */ else /* not ok  */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if(preg_match) to know how to use it, use this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html